# GSON does not deserialize reference to outer class

Tags: java, json, serialization, deserialization, gson

On my Java application, I defined two classes, called `A` and `B` where `B` is inner class of `A`. Both are defined as serializable

```
public class A implements Serializable {

    int attrParent;
    List<B> items = new ArrayList<B>();

    public void setAttrParent(int attrParent) {
        this.attrParent = attrParent;
    }

    public int getAttrParent() {
        return attrParent;
    }

    public class B implements Serializable {

        private int attr;

        public void setAttr(int attr) {
            this.attr = attr;
        }

        public int getAttr() {
            return attr;
        }

        public int getSomeCalculationValue() {
            return this.attr * A.this.attrParent; // Problems occurs here
        }

    }
}
```

**Before** serializing this object with GSON, `getSomeCalculationValue` works fine. But, **after** serializing and deserializing, `getSomeCalculationValue` fails with a `NullPointerException`.

This happens because the inner class `B` doesn´t have a reference to outer class `A` anymore, so, `A.this` fails.

Does anybody knows how could I solve this, that is restoring the inner to outer reference while deserializing this object?

Comment: Please show your serialization and deserialization process as well as a sample gson. I don't see why you need `Serializable` here.

Answer (score 7):

As Gson documentation says:

> Gson can serialize static nested classes quite easily.
>
> Gson can also deserialize static nested classes. However, **Gson can
>   not automatically deserialize the pure inner classes since their
>   no-args constructor also need a reference to the containing Object
>   which is not available at the time of deserialization**. You can
>   address this problem by either making the inner class static or by
>   providing a custom InstanceCreator for it.

Changing B to a static inner class is not possible since your method needs a reference to the outer class in `getSomeCalculationValue`, so, I've tried to solve your problem with an `InstanceCreator` but solution was a bit ugly, so I propose you to use a custom deserialized. I changed your `A` class a little, making items public  to make easier to create the example I show you.

```
public class ADeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<A> {
    public A deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT,
        JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {

    A a = new A();
    a.attrParent = json.getAsJsonObject().get("attrParent").getAsInt();
    JsonArray ja = json.getAsJsonObject().get("items").getAsJsonArray();
    for(JsonElement e: ja){
        B b = a.new B();
        b.setAttr(e.getAsJsonObject().get("attr").getAsInt());
        a.items.add(b);
    }
    return a;
    }

}
```

And this is how I use it:

```
public class Q19449761 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        A a = new A();
        a.setAttrParent(3);
        B b = a.new B();
        b.setAttr(10);
        a.items.add(b);
        System.out.println("Before serializing: "  + a.items.get(0).getSomeCalculationValue());

        Gson g = new Gson();

        String json = g.toJson(a, A.class);
        System.out.println("JSON string: " + json);

        A test2 = g.fromJson(json, A.class);

        try {
            System.out.println("After standard deserialization: " +test2.items.get(0).getSomeCalculationValue());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
        builder.registerTypeAdapter(A.class, new ADeserializer());

        A test3 = builder.create().fromJson(json, A.class);

        System.out.println("After custom deserialization: " + test3.items.get(0).getSomeCalculationValue());

    }

}
```

And this is my execution:

```
Before serializing: 30
JSON string: {"attrParent":3,"items":[{"attr":10}]}
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at stackoverflow.questions.q19449761.A$B.getSomeCalculationValue(A.java:32)
    at stackoverflow.questions.q19449761.Q19449761.main(Q19449761.java:26)
After custom deserialization: 30
```

Two final notes:

1. You do not need to implement `Serializable` interface, JSON has nothing in common with Java serialization
2. My deserializer lacks of null cases management, you should complete for null JSON or null fields.

Comment: 'static inner' is a contradiction in terms.