# Gson nodes/links object mapping

Tags: java, json, jackson, gson

I have a JSON file which have separate subsections and all the subsections have same type of data, is there any way we can directly map these inner objects

```
{
  "pre-execution": {
    "nodes": [],
    "links": []
  },
  "execution": {
    "nodes": [],
    "links": []
  },
  "completion": {
    "nodes": [],
    "links": []
  }
}
```

I am interested only in node and link type of data and not bothered about from which category it belongs to.

My class structure looks like this

```
public class NodeElement{
  private List<Node> nodes;
  private List<Link> links;
}
```

Is there any way i can directly map it through Gson library. The code i am using is giving null

```
   Gson gson=new Gson();
   NodeElement nodeElements=gson.fromJson(jsonString,NodeElement.class);
```

the reason i got because it is not following the correct hierarchy. The point is I am interested in only `Node` and `Link` so why should worry for the hierarchy.

Any other library can be used if not Gson?

i tried doing this way

```
for(Map.Entry<String,JsonElement> entry : entrySet){
        if(entry.getKey().contains("node")){
            siteFlowElement.addNodes((List<GoJSNode>) obj.get(entry.getKey()));
        }
        if(entry.getKey().contains("link")){
            siteFlowElement.addLinks((List<GoJSLink>) obj.get(entry.getKey()));
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Nodes"+siteFlowElement.getNodes());
    System.out.println("Links"+siteFlowElement.getLinks());
```

But it is returning null,

Json object is populating fine

Comment: You can take a look @ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19551242/parsing-a-complex-json-object-using-gson-in-java This might help

Comment: it is not helpful , as the question is for parsing json through Gson , i know that already the problem is that i don't want to make exact hierarchy of class as i am interested in only node and links

Answer (score 1):

```
JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
JsonObject o = parser.parse(your json string).getAsJsonObject();
```

After getting the JsonObject Iterate through the object and get all the nodes and link inside of a list for all the keys

eg -  `Set<Entry<String, JsonElement>> entrySet = jsonObject.entrySet();`

Comment: i did something like this                                                 
    ~ Set<Entry<String, JsonElement>> entrySet = obj.entrySet();
      for(Map.Entry<String,JsonElement> entry : entrySet){
       if(entry.getKey().contains("node")){
        siteFlowElement.addNodes((List<GoJSNode>) obj.get(entry.getKey()));
       }
       if(entry.getKey().contains("link")){
        siteFlowElement.addLinks((List<GoJSLink>) obj.get(entry.getKey()));
       }
      }

Comment: what is the error can you update it in the question its hard to figure out it out in the comment section

Comment: it is giving null values in node and link...Can u tell the problem in code

Comment: is the jsonObject getting populated fine ? did you try and print that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147262/discussion-between-ravi-and-rahul-singh).