# Inner class reference to enclosing class instance is null

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, inner-classes, gson

I have a class that has an inner class and a collection of the inner instances:

```
public class Outer {

    private List<Inner> items = new ArrayList<Inner>(); 

    ... 

    public List<Inner> getItems(){
        return this.items;
    }

    public int getOuterX() {
        ...
    }
    ...

    public class Inner {
        ... 
        public int getInnerX(){     
            return Outer.this.getOuterX(); // this line throws the exception 
        }
    }
}
```

In other class I iterate over the items of an instance of `Outer` and call `getInnerX()` to each one:

```
for (Outer.Inner item : outer.getItems()) {
    item.getInnerX();
}
```

A `NullPointerException` is thrown inside `getInnerX()` because `Outer.this` is `null`.

I don't know how this can happen.

**EDIT:**

I was preparing the example like @Sotirios Delimanolis asked for and i could not reproduce the error. 
So its something that i did not include in the question.

I am using `retrofit2` and `Outer` object is created based on a `json` response from the server.

The item attribute of `Outer` has annotations for the `GSon` converter:

```
@SerializedName("items")
@Expose
private List<Inner> items = new ArrayList<Inner>();
```

Outer has no constructor defined neither does Inner.

Here is the stack trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String 
com.example.server_comunication.datatypes.OrderResponse$Order.getStatus()' on a null object reference
      at com.example.server_comunication.datatypes.OrderResponse$Order$Supply.forPlacement(OrderResponse.java:408)
      at com.example.server_comunication.datatypes.OrderResponse$Order$Supply.getRemaining(OrderResponse.java:423)
      at com.example.uiHelpers.UIFactoryPanels.drawPanelSuppliesEditor(UIFactoryPanels.java:142)
      at com.example.OrderFragment.onCreateView(OrderFragment.java:85)
      at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2053)
      at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:894)
      at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
      at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:833)
      at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1452)
      at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:483)
      at android.support.v13.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:145)
      at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1177)
      at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1025)
      at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1545)
      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
      at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:727)
      at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:463)
      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
      at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:668)
      at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:735)
      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
      at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
      at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
      at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
      at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
      at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
      at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
      at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
      at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2560)
      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2001)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1166)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1372)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1054)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5779)
      at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
      at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
      at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
      at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
```

Comment: @daniel I think [tag:android] is relevant. This shouldn't be possible in vanilla Java without bytecode manipulation. Something in Android might be causing this. Pablo, can you provide a [MCVE]?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Good point, rolled it back.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, i am working on the example. Just like i posted it, i couldn't reproduce the error (i simplified too much), so i am adding new information involved. Thanks.

Comment: May be `OuterClass.this` is innocent and NPE happens insideof `getOuterX()` ?

Comment: Please provide the stack trace so we can stop guessing. Edit it into your question.

Comment: Oh, this is Gson's fault. I think there's a duplicate somewhere. One sec.

Comment: Basically this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19449761/gson-does-not-deserialize-reference-to-outer-class

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Retrofit uses Gson and Gson cheats. (As of this writing) It uses the `sun.misc.Unsafe` class to instantiate your class with `allocateInstance`. This skips any constructors altogether.

In the case of an inner class, [any declared constructor will implicitly declare its first parameter as the enclosing type to represent the enclosing class' instance](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.1). There's no way for Gson to create an instance of that enclosing class, but even if it did, that doesn't matter. Gson skips the constructor altogether, leaving that implicit `Outer.this` reference as `null`.

The easiest solution is to change your design, get rid of the inner class(es). Alternatively, you can register and use a custom deserializer. There are examples in the posts below.

Related posts:

- [GSON does not deserialize reference to outer class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19449761/gson-does-not-deserialize-reference-to-outer-class)
- [Is default no-args constructor mandatory for Gson?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18645050/is-default-no-args-constructor-mandatory-for-gson)

Comment: Thank you very much. I use inner classes to match the json structure data coming from the server. I will change my design like you said.